# Como criar Array com conteúdo do BD

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estou tentando criar um array com o conteúdo de uma `tabela` do meu `banco` mas não sei como, tentei fazer isso:

```
// ATRIBUI UMA CONEXÃO PDO   
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
// ATRIBUI UMA INSTÂNCIA DA CLASSE CRUD
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'cadAgendaEvento');

// BUSCANDO EVENTOS
$sqlEvento = "SELECT * FROM `cadAgendaEvento`";

$dados = array();

foreach ($sqlEvento as $Retorno) {                      

    $dados = $Retorno;  

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "success" => 1,
            "result" => $dados
        )
    );                              
}
```

Gostaria de saber se esse formato é o correto, aparentemente não está me retornando nada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por semelhança com código, presumo que esteja usando essa biblioteca: http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/crud-generico-com-php-e-pdo

Se for o caso, basta usar o método:

```
public function getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParams=null, $fetchAll=TRUE)`
```

Por exemplo:

```
// BUSCANDO EVENTOS
$dados = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sqlEventos);
```

Nesse ponto a variável `$dados` já será um array com os dados do banco.

Pode percorrer esses dados usando um `foreach`:

```
foreach ($dados as $dado) {   
    echo $dado;               
}
```

Se quiser imprimir um json da forma que mostrou no seu código, não precisa do `for`:

```
echo json_encode(array(
        "success" => 1,
        "result" => $dados
));
```

Comment: Olá @PanterA, valeu pela dica, realmente estou usando a biblioteca mencionada, mas me diz uma uma coisa, esse último exemplo pega todos os registros do banco e monta esse array?

Comment: @adventistapr, sim. Como o terceiro parâmetro do método `getSQLGeneric`, quando omitido, contém o valor `TRUE`, a variável `$dados` será sempre um array com todos os registros sua query. A documentação do [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) do PHP tem mais detalhes de como isso funciona.